# I foolishly detached the fiddly "push pin" cooler from a client's old PC. Here are some possible plans of action. What would you do, and why?

Tags: repair, overheating, thermal-paste, cpu-cooler, intel-pentium

A client of mine brought me an outdated home PC.

The specs: It's a compact tower PC, sixteen inches tall. It includes a Pentium Dual-Core E2200 and 1 GB of RAM. An independent computer store built it in 2008.

The problem: It always shut down after a couple of minutes of use.

The client told me he doesn't want to spend more than about US$50.

I used the BIOS setup utility's hardware-monitoring feature to check how hot the CPU was running. I then did some online research and decided that the problem was caused by CPU overheating.

Without thinking, I foolishly removed the CPU's stock heatsink/fan assembly ("cooler"). (I neglected to consider that I'd have to regrease the CPU after doing so. I've never regreased a CPU in my life.)

I don't really want to learn how to regrease a CPU. But, even though the client was only willing to spend about $50, I guess I now have no choice but to learn how do do so, then to regrease the CPU for free. (If I am wrong on this point, and actually do not have to regrease anything, then please correct me.)

I've bought alcohol and thermal grease.

The cooler attaches to the motherboard using "Intel push pin" fasteners. Such fasteners weren't designed for ease of use: instead, they were designed to be cheap to make. (Source: nwrtarget on the HardOCP forums.) It's easy for a novice like me to install them wrong.

To save effort, I plan to reattach the cooler with the motherboard still in the case. I know that, if I do so, it's possible to make a mistake which is undetectable until I boot up the machine.

As I see it, three possible plans of action are as follows.

**Plan 1:** Reinstall the stock cooler.

- Regrease the CPU.
- Reattach the cooler.
- Temporarily disable CPU throttling.
- Run some CPU stress-test software.

**Plan 2:** Remove the motherboard then reinstall the stock cooler.

- Disconnect a bunch of cables.
- Remove the motherboard.
- Regrease the CPU.
- Reattach the cooler.
- Visually verify that all four push pins are securely attached.
- Reinstall the motherboard.
- Temporarily disable CPU throttling.
- Run some CPU stress-test software.

**Plan 3:** Buy and install a replacement cooler and backplate, and eat the costs.

- Buy a replacement cooler and backplate at my own expense.
- Disconnect a bunch of cables.
- Lift up the motherboard.
- Install the backplate.
- Regrease the CPU.
- Install the cooler.
- Temporarily disable CPU throttling.
- Run some CPU stress-test software.
- Charge the client $50 for labor, but zero for the new cooler.

**Or I could choose some other plan of action.**

I'm leaning towards Plan 1.

If you were in my situation, which plan of action would you take, and why?

<sub>P.S. If you can edit this question to make it shorter, please do so.</sub>

Comment: Regrease, as you put it, is easy.  Rubbing alcohol or a real clean to remove the old.  Then just apply the new in a thin layer across the surface.  The downward pressure of the spring lock will spread it out the rest of the way.

Comment: Just spend $10 for the grease and be done with it.

Comment: I understand that you're nervous because you've never done this before, but you're making a bit of a mountain out of this mole hill. Option 1 is your best course of action. Clean the old thermal compound off with some rubbing alcohol, apply a drop of new thermal compound to the CPU, affix the heat sink, done. There are a bazillion articles and videos on how to do this, of which this is one: http://www.maximumpc.com/article/howtos/howto_install_cpu_and_apply_thermal_paste

Comment: @cybernard: The problem is that "Intel push pin" fasteners aren't always so easy to fasten correctly.

Comment: @Ramhound: I've already bought grease and alcohol.

Comment: @cybernard: The problem with Option 1 is that it's hard to tell if an "Intel push pin" fastener is installed correctly or not.

Comment: @unforgettableid So, if you install it incorrectly, detach it and install it again. (You'll know because the CPU won't fool properly.)

Comment: @unforgettableid - Its not difficult.  You can only installed it one way.

Comment: It's a piece of cake!